# Creating a grid figure in Matlab with coordinates labelled

Tags: matlab, grid, plot, matlab-figure

How do I write a function in Matlab to generate an `nxn` grid? I'm working on a numerical problem and I'm getting quite tired of drawing very large grids by hand -- extremeley tedious and impractical, but without this I would have a hard time progressing through the problem. Essentially I would need this to help me get through my code and help debug.

1. figure needs to display an `nxn` grid (just like graph paper)
2. points/coordinates labeled `(x,y)`, beginning with `(1,1)` in the bottom let corner and `(n+1,n+1)` in the top right corner, i.e. `n` is the number of "boxes"

**Update:**
 3. If possible, be able to highlight/color certain parts of the grid

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I get the question. Do you mean something like the image below? The code used to generate it is

```
n = 50;
plot(0,0)
xlim([1,n+1])
ylim([1,n+1])
set(gca,'xtick',1:n+1)
set(gca,'ytick',1:n+1)
grid
axis square
```

[image]